# what's the difference between jquery lazyload and JAIL?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lazy-loading

Tried to search online but couldn't find any kind of (ideally independent) comparison or review of the differences between two image lazy-load jquery plugins:

- [lazyload](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)
- [jQuery Asynchronous Image Loader - JAIL](http://www.sebastianoarmelibattana.com/projects/jail)

Are there any particular use-cases where one is better than the other?

Answer (score 0):

Literally, there is no difference between this two jquery plugin.

Actually the author of [JAIL](http://jquer.in/jquery-ajax/jail/), Sebastiano Armeli explained the reasons of writing JAIL [here](http://blog.sebarmeli.com/2011/01/04/reasons-why-i-wrote-the-plugin-jquery-asynchronous-image-loader-jail/).

But I think now [lazy load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) plugin has been improved and usable. So you can choose any of these two.

These are basic calls of these two plugins:

**JAIL**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
      $('img.lazy').jail();
      });
      </script>
```

**LazyLoad**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
     $("img.lazy").lazyload();
  });
  </script>
```